# My Nav-Menu is supposed to move off screen when closed, but instead shifts to the right and extends the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, mobile-website

I created a nav menu which is supposed to move off screen to the right when I close it, and return back on screen when I click the menu button. However, in the opened state, it is in the expected position on screen, but when I close it, instead of disappearing to the right, it shifts to the right zooming the whole screen out and revealing a white space at the bottom of the screen. I tried moving it to the left side instead and that seems to work just fine, I'm a beginner at this stuff and very confused now.

[Page when you first load up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Zz2.jpg)

[Page when menu is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwofY.jpg)

[When I try closing the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U91mX.jpg)

HTML code:

```
 <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
      <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">PROPERTY</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>

    </nav>
```

My JS code:

`

```
  var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

  function showMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "0";
  }

  function hideMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
  }

</script> `
```

CSS code:

```
`@media(max-width: 700px){

  .text-box h1{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav-links ul li{
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    background: #ec1212ca;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  nav .fa{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav-links ul{
    padding: 30px;
  }
}`
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add your html data.

Comment: done, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I was able to recreate the problem you were having.

If I'm right, the issue you were having was because the menu parent container did not have:

1. "position: relative;" OR
2. "overflow: hidden;" OR
3. BOTH were missing

Without seeing the full code, I'm left to guesswork, but adding those properties to the parent node of the .nav-links div should fix the problem.

Also, you probably will not want to have the menu inside of the `<nav></nav>` section if you wanted the height to be the full height of the page.

I've put together what I think you were trying to accomplish; if it's not right just comment below and I'll try to adjust it.

```js
 var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

 function toggleMenu() {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("showMenu");
 }
```

```css
  .text-box h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ec1212ca;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav-links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }

/* added css */

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.showMenu {
  right: 0 !important;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>

        <button class="fa fa-bars" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
      </nav>

      <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">PROPERTY</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```